# How to prevent a file under user folder to be deleted?

Tags: nautilus, root, delete, users, rm

How can I make some file impossible to be deleted by user even if it is under his/her home folder?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is possible to make a file impossible to delete, even from root, on an ext2/3/4 filesystem, changing a file system attribute of the file:

```
$ cd
$ touch dummy
$ sudo chattr +i dummy
$ rm dummy
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file `dummy'? y
rm: cannot remove `dummy': Operation not permitted
$ sudo rm dummy
[sudo] password for enzotib: 
rm: cannot remove `dummy': Operation not permitted
$
```

More information on `chattr` and `lsattr` manual pages.

If later you want to delete the file you should use

```
sudo chattr -i dummy
```

before using `rm`.

There are two drawbacks to this:

1. you have to be root to change
   attributes;
2. you can forget about the attributes of that file or the way to change them, so that it seem you cannot delete the file anymore.

Comment: Is there a way to use this and maintain other permissions? For example, still allowing the user and group permissions for `rwx` of sub-directories and files.